# Nuget Powershell: How to pass project folder to command

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I have some small c# console applications whose path have been added to the system path and at such can be called anywhere. Because of this, I can run these applications from the package manager (PM) console.

This thing now is how do I pass a path to one of the projects to the document. E.g. one of the console applications is "document". I want to execute 
`document --path=[path to .Model project]`

Given that the solution has three(3) projects with one active, how should the command be written so that it is passed in the path to the active or selected project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NuGet Package Manager console provides a [Get-Project cmdlet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Get-Project) that can be used to return the active project, or a particular project if the -Name parameter is passed. Two examples are shown below.

```
Get-Project
Get-Project -Name MyProjectName
```

The [project object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx) returned has a FileName property which returns the filename of the project. You could then pass that to the Split-Path cmdlet to get the directory. Doing this one line at a time:

```
$p = Get-Project
Split-Path $p.FileName
```

Or in one line:

```
Split-Path (Get-Project).FileName
```